# how to measure duration of the call with the call back and export it as nodejs module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The parameters will be: (functionToCall, argumentArray, numberOfCalls). Which returns an object that would tell us the number of successes & failures, for each category: average time, min & max. The callback can be assumed to be function(error, result).Psuedo code will be like

```
   measureWithCallback = function(functionToCall, argumentArray,numberOfCalls, callback) {
      var perfResults = { success: { }, failure: { } };
       ... measure ...
      callback(null, perfResults);
    }
```

call functionToCall, one at a time, numberOfCalls times with arguments argumentArray

```
    argumentArray.push(function(error, success) {
        // record results
    // call next
     });
```

to call a function with provided arguments:

```
 functionToCall.apply(argumentArray);
```

Comment: What constitutes success and failure for the `functionToCall`?  Does failure just mean that the call throws?

Comment: Yes failure means throws

Comment: I am not sure about success but callback tells us whether its having an error or not if not error than it is success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood before and did not realize that the function you are testing (`functionToCall`) also needs to be passed a callback.

```
function measureWithCallback(functionToCall,
                             argumentArray,
                             numberOfCalls,
                             callback) {
    var args        = argumentArray.concat([callFn]);
        callI       = 0,
        perfResults = { success: [], failure: [] },
        start       = 0;

    callFn();

    function callFn(err) {
        // Store the results for this call.
        if (callI > 0)
            perfResults[err ? 'failure' : 'success'].push(Date.now() - start);

        if (callI < numberOfCalls) {
            callI++;
            start = Date.now();
            functionToCall.apply(null, args);
        } else {
            callback(null, aggregateResults(perfResults));
        }
    }

    function aggregateResults(results) {
        return {
            success : totals(results.success),
            failure : totals(results.failure)
        };

        function totals(arr) {
            return {
                avg   : arr.reduce(add, 0) / arr.length,
                max   : Math.max.apply(Math, arr),
                min   : Math.min.apply(Math, arr),
                count : arr.length
            };

            function add(x, y) {
                return x + y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`measureWithCallback` can be tested with expressions like::

```
measureWithCallback(
    fs.appendFile.bind(fs),
    ['./node.txt', 'testing.\n'],
    3000,
    console.log.bind(console)
);
```

And:

```
measureWithCallback(testFn, [], 30, console.log.bind(console));

function testFn(cb) {
    var r = Math.random();
    setTimeout(cb.bind(null, r > 0.5 ? null : new Error()), Math.floor(r * 1000));
}
```

The second example produces output like:

```
null { success: { avg: 802.4444444444445, max: 996, min: 506, count: 18 },
failure: { avg: 287.9166666666667, max: 485, min: 15, count: 12 } }
```

The returned numbers (min, max, and average) are the elapsed time in milliseconds.